# Построчный вывод из XML в HTML?

Tags: html, xml

Стоит задача, есть `xml` документ из него нужно взять данные и вывести в html документ, то есть сделать сцепку. Но почему-то у меня из `xml` документа данные не подтягиваются в `hmtl`, подскажите, пожалуйста, где допущена ошибка?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="lab1.css"?>
<!-- lab1.xml -->
<file_1>
  <bookstore xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <table>
   <tr>
    <book data-title="Рассматриваются теория и практика речевой деятельности. Представлены ее биологический, социальный, культурно-исторический и  
        лингвистический аспекты. Подробно освещаются исполнительные механизмы коммуникативной системы человека: порождение и восприятие устных и письменных сообщений">
        <th><author>Абелева И.Ю.</author>
        <name>Речь о речи. Коммуникативная система человека.</name>
        <publish>— М.: Логос,</publish>
        <year>2004.</year> 
        <str>- 304 с.</str></th>  
    </book>
       </tr>

    </table>

    </bookstore>
</file_1>
```

Документа Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xml id="dsoBook" src="lab1.xml"></xml>
    <h2>Список книг</h2>
    <table datasrc="#dsoBook" border="6" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
        <thead style="background-color: maroon">
            <th>Автор</th>
            <th>Названия</th>
            <th>Издательство</th>
            <th>Год издания</th>
            <th>Страниц</th> 
        </thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><span DATAFLD="author" style="font-style: italic"></span></td>
            <td><span DATAFLD="name"></span></td>
            <td><span DATAFLD="publish"></span></td>
            <td><span DATAFLD="year"></span></td>
            <td><span DATAFLD="str"></span></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```